# How can I get path aliases arguments from a URL in a template?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a content type which has an automatic path alias to `latest-news/[title]` (e.g. latest-news/example-news-title).

I need to get the first part of the path alias in my `page.tpl.php` file, but when I use `arg(0)` I am given `node` and not `latest-news`.

How can I get the first part of an aliases URL in a page template?

Comment: Templating by aliases instead of templating by what you want to template seems risky. Why do you need that? why don't you template by content type?

Answer (score 2):

You can use function [drupal_get_path_alias()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) to get the path alias, then [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) to get the first component of the path, like so.

```
echo strstr(drupal_get_path_alias(), '/', TRUE);
```